# Getting SE, p-value & t-value in seperate columns

Tags: r, logistic-regression, stargazer

the title says it all. I'm trying to figure out, how to get SE, p-value, & t-value in their own columns. So they are in the same line as the coeff and not beneath it.

This is my code so far:

```
stargazer(m1, type = "html", style = "asr", intercept.top = T, 
          intercept.bottom = F, single.row = F, report=("vcstp")) %>% 
    write_lines(file = "test.html")
```

So far, it puts all the data in to one column which makes the output way too long. I'd like to have it in their seperate columns for better readability.

This is what it looks like now (bad): https://ibb.co/8r0B5Dy

This is the direction i want to go (better): https://ibb.co/0Zm1XXD

Any ideas?

Greets,

Aves

Tried several commands, including single.row = T, but that only puts SE behind the coeff. The rest is still beneath it.

Comment: [‘stargazer’ is a terrible package.](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/comment/dkgw9q1/) I strongly recommend against using it. Use anything else instead, e.g. ‘[modelsummary](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/)’ or ‘[texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=texreg)’.